# Copy *.csv file to view in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv

I want to import data from *.csv file to view in the PostgreSQL with 9.3 version. Here is the following script I have tried.

**Example**:

```
\copy "viewName" from 'D:\filename.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

**Error**

```
ERROR:  cannot copy to view "viewName"
```

**Questions**:

- Where I am going wrong?
- Or I need to copy it into table then select it from there?

Comment: you can only COPY directly to a table, not a view

Comment: IMO `COPY aTable FROM D:\filename.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;` and then `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW viewName AS (SELECT * FROM aTable )`

Comment: @dude, Yup! I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html:

> COPY can only be used with plain tables, not with views. However, you can write COPY (SELECT * FROM viewname) TO ....

Since `COPY` is the basis for `\copy`, you might want to try your code with a table instead of a view and the select from there.